# TFS Git Branch Documentation

Tags: git, tfs, git-branch

We're using TFS & Git for our source control and we have a large development team. A problem is that a lot of branches get created but are never subsequently cleaned up. Is there a way to add comments or descriptions that are branch specific and do not get merged when making a pull request so we can help make sure people know what a branch is for and if it's no longer needed?

We are using (or attempting to use) intelligent branch naming practices to help mitigate this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your developers merge code via pull requests (and they should!), you can optionally delete the branch after the PR is completed.

Past that, it's mostly down to naming practices. You'll commonly see people using branch structures like `/dev/dmann/someThing` for short-lived, individual branches versus `/release/4.5` for stable release branches versus `/features/bigAwesomeFeature` for longer-running feature branches.